# Handling password confirmation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a User entity that needs to be persisted on the database. I need to know if its okay to compare two passwords values the user enters in the registration page in the following way;

**Registration View**

```
<form:form action="addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
...
<form:password path="userPassword" id="password" />
<input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword">
...
</form>
```

And then, in the Controller,

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, String cpassword) {
...
*service method to compare user.getUserPassword() and cpassword*
}
```

And the User entity for clarity;

**User Entity**

```
public class User {

private int userId;
private String userName;
private String userFirstName;
private String userLastName;
private String userEmail;
private String userPhone;
private String userPassword;

}
```

Basically, the value of cpassword is being passed as a String attribute to the handler method in the controller. Is this method okay? Is it safe? This is for a little project I'm doing to learn Spring MVC.

Comment: For the little learning project its fine and safe and dont worry about it.

Comment: Are you passing the users real password to the front-end? Kindly dont do that..even if it is a learning project....

Comment: This is valid for little projects but you can improve this by using these various types of encryptions algorithms. First learn basics of spring security then move for it:}

Comment: @SusanMustafa no, I'm not directly passing the password to the frontend in my code. I just need to know if passing the value of cpassword as a plain String somehow makes it accessible anywhere

Comment: @AayushSaini AjayKumar thank you, I'm not worried about Spring security I'm going to start learning it next but I just thought It'd help me learn MVC if I did a little project

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the password in clear text in your database, but instead store a hashed password.
If you want to compare the stored password with a passed in password for some reason, you need to hash the passed in password with the same hash algorithm and compare the passwords. Then you know they are the same, but you don't know the value of them.

Look up password hashing (random article I found without reading...but will give you a hint what it is about https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/ )

Comment: Thanks for this I'll look into the article. I still havent started Spring security but I just need to know if passing the confirmpassword value as a string to the controller from the view makes it accessible to a user

Comment: What do you mean "accessible to a user"? To other users of your web app? That should not be the case. But with what you said `compare user.getUserPassword() and cpassword`, it looks like you store the password in the database as plain text, so that is why I mentioned the hashing of passwords.